# Mac | Terminal: Move multiple files located in CSV to different directory

Tags: bash, terminal, applescript, automator

I can't seem to figure out this one.

I have a csv file, 2 columns. ColumnsA contains the path to a file and ColumnB the destination of said file. Total rows 1,000.

I will like terminal to loop and move each file located in columnA to the destination in columnB
[image]

In terminal, I tried using this:

```
for file in $(cat ~/downloads/Mover.csv); do mv ...
```

I can't figure out the next piece of the command. Can you please help?

Raw file Format: csv (comma delimiter)
The raw file is as shown in the screenshot. ColumnA contains the path of each pdf that needs to be inserted inside the folder in ColumnB

- each pdf file is unique.
- one file per folder

I'm very new to the world of terminal. Please let me know what I can provide

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The CSV format isn't very friendly for UNIX standard tools, but as long as you don't have commas, double-quotes or newlines in your content then you can use this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

while IFS=',' read -r location new
do
    mv -i "$location" "$new/"
done < <(sed $'s/\r$//' file.csv)
```

<sup>I'm supposing that `new` is a directory</sup>

Comment: It can't identify the location of the files, the Folder containing "pdf" --- for this case the "downloads" folder. I also try putting the location of the pdf files in a different directory and updating the path. Doing so and executing, the location folder gets rename to - > "new?". Thank you so much for helping with this :)

Comment: You seem to have Windows line endings in your CSV file. The updated answer gets rid of them.